# Adding height to polygon with different height points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, slope

I have a polygonZ (representing a gravel deposit area) that currently has a "flat" top, but in reality it slopes in different directions. I have the height data for 6 points (in red on the image) around its edges (barely visible stipled line) and would like to add this to the polygon to calculate exact cubic meter filling. The slope is fairly linear from one edge to another. How can I do this?

I use arcgis 10.3 with a basic license.

[image]

Comment: For 6 points, can't you manually add the Z value for those vertices?

Comment: @klewis good idea, that genuinely did not cross my mind. The only downside is that there are many vertices so it will take some time to add the values manually to all of them, and it will be a be a bit inaccurate since I only know the values for these 6 points.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.